# Need help about string match in web scraping, python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I try to extract something from a webpage. And firstly, I used BeautifulSoup to extract a div named "scores" which includes several images like this

```
<img class="sprite-rating_s_fill rating_s_fill s45" src="http://e2.tacdn.com/img2/x.gif" alt="4.5 of 5 stars">
```

And I want to extract the score in this image, for this case it is "4.5". 
So I try to do it in this way:

```
pattern = re.compile('<img.*?alt="(.*?) of 5 stars">', re.S)
items = re.findall(pattern, scores)
```

But it does not work.
I am new to web scraping, so could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BeautifulSoup actually makes it really easy to extract information from tags like that! Assuming that `scores` is a BeautifulSoup `Tag` object (which you can read about [in their documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#tag)), what you want to do is extract the `src` attribute from the tag:

```
src = scores['src']
```

For the example you just gave, src should be `u'4.5 out of 5 stars'`. Now you just need to strip out the `' out of 5 stars'`:

```
removeIndex = src.index(' out of 5 stars')
score = src[:removeIndex]
```

And you'll be left with a `score` of `'4.5'`. (If you want to manipulate it as a number, you'll have to do `score = float(score)`.

Comment: It works, thank you very much. Would you please also give some suggestion about the way I match the string? I still want to figure out why it is wrong